# What does the output of PHP function 'mysqli_prepare' mean

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am new to PHP and prepared SQL sentences and I got one question when reading the documentation.

Function ['mysqli.prepare'](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns a boolean value when executed. According to the documentation:

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

That's not a very detailed description of the returned value. I mean, when does it exactly fail? Only when the SQL syntax is not correct? Or when we try to execute it and it does not work for any other reason (I base this last supposition on the example shown on the documentation, where almost all the script is enclosed in an `if` statement)

Based on this, I also have a second question: is it a good practice to run `mysqli_prepare()` together with an `if`? Or should the `if` statement be written when we run the `$stmt->execute();` function later on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are too many reasons why a query can fail. But when the query failed you can get the error message with `mysqli_error()` and `mysqli_errno()`. When the query failed the `mysqli_prepare()` function will return `FALSE` (and not a MySQLi prepared statement object) to indicate that there was an error. You have to check the return value with an `if()` statement to handle this case. If you don't check it and try to run `$stmt->execute();` you will get an error that you cannot run the `execute()` method on a boolean value (the value `false`).

For your second question: You have to check the return value of `mysqli_prepare()` and you have to check the return value of `mysqli_stmt_execute()`. You cannot skip the check, otherwise you get errors like [mysql_fetch_array()/mysql_fetch_assoc()/mysql_fetch_row()/mysql_num_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc).

Comment: You can skip the check and you do not need to check with `if` statement. Actually this is a terrible practice and should be avoided! [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)